# duplicity: accidentally switched sign keys during backups

Tags: duplicity, duplicity-backup

I've been using duplicity for several months to back up my mac. I recently needed to do a restore, but it looks like at some point I switched keys. Because if I use Key A, it starts to open a few volumes then complains that a volume was signed with Key B, but if I switch to Key B, it complains that the first volume was signed with Key A. The manpage indicates multiple sign keys are not allowed. Did I wreck my backup? Both GPG keys are on my keyring, just some volumes were backed up with one, some with the other. Advice?
Thanks,
PeterT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my `conf` file, setting `GPG_KEY='KEYA,KEYB'` and `GPG_KEY_SIGN='disabled'` solved the problem. I have no idea why duply started using two different GPG keys from my ring (probably because I was still learning), but I am now deleting my entire backup and starting again (and removing all duply GPG keys and making a new one).